# How do I check if a Firestore collection is empty?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-material, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Angular and Angularfire2.

I would like to check if a Firestore collection is empty. I'm making a todo app and I would like to show an empty state container as part of the [Material guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/empty-states.html).

Here's my data structure:

```
users/
  userID/
    todos/
      // etc.
```

I'm using the following code:

```html
<div class="empty-state-container" *ngIf="isTodosEmpty">
    <div class="empty-state-div">
        <h2>All todos have been done!</h2>
        <p>Go reward yourself with exercising, reading or your favourite hobby.</p>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="newTodo()" color="primary">Create a new todo</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- ... -->
```

My component:

```ts
export class MyComponent {
    isTodosEmpty: boolean;

    constructor(
        private fs: AngularFirestore,
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        // ...
    ) {
        afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            console.log(user);
            this.currentUser = user.uid;
            this.todosCollection = this.fs.collection(`users/${this.currentUser}/todos`);
            this.todos$ = this.todosCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
                return actions.map(a => {
                    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as TodoItem;
                    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data };
                });
            });
        } else {
            console.warn('Current user doesn\'t exist yet!');
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="todos$ | async; let todos; else nocontent">
    <div *ngFor="let todo of todos">
        {{todo | json}}
    </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #nocontent>
    <div class="empty-state-container">
        <div class="empty-state-div">
            <h2>All todos have been done!</h2>
            <p>Go reward yourself with exercising, reading or your favourite hobby.</p>
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="newTodo()" color="primary">Create a new todo</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

`<ng-template #nocontent>` this part will show if `todos$` is empty.

Comment: A problem here is that a blank area will still be shown if the collection's contents are empty. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it by following @Hareesh's answer but instead, I checked if the length of the `todos$` `Observable` (`Array`) is bigger than `0` and if isn't, it'll still show the empty state container:

```html
<ng-template #emptystate>
    <div class="empty-state-container">
        <div class="empty-state-div">
            <h2>All todos have been done!</h2>
            <p>Go reward yourself with exercising, reading or your favourite hobby.</p>
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="newTodo()" color="primary">Create a new todo</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-container *ngIf="(todos$ | async)?.length > 0; else: emptystate">
    <!-- ... -->
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This way also fine. why i choose above method is i can use `let todos` multiple times in my template. i ran in to problem if i use observable `todos$` multiple times

Comment: @Hareesh I actually have a `<mat-nav-list>` used for all the todos.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer:

```
<div *ngIf="( todos$ | async)?.length > 0">Populated</div>
<div *ngIf="( todos$ | async)?.length == 0">Empty</div>
```

You'd just want to stay away from `!( (todos$ | async)?.length > 0 )` because that would always start it off in the second (empty) state, then automatically switch it over to the populated state when it pops in a second later.